# Reduction of benzylic alcohol and halide using H2 and Pd

Tags: synthesis, hydrogen, catalysis, organic-reduction, drugs

I am studying drug synthesis, and I found some examples that uses $\ce{H_2}$ and Pd/C or Pd/$\ce{BaSO_4}$ as catalytic hydrogenation reagents for reduction of alcohol or halide in benzylic position. But I have never heard this situation in organic chemistry textbook, and also I have tried search about it but I couldn't found generalized explanation. Is it unusual case of catalytic hydrogenation? Below are the examples.

[image: Synthesis of Zolpidem]

In the synthesis of Zolpidem, chloro group is reduced by $\ce{H_2}$ and Pd/$\ce{BaSO_4}$.

[image: Synthesis of Methamphetamine]

In the synthesis of Methamphetamine, hydroxyl group is reduced by $\ce{H_2}$ and Pd/C or Pd/$\ce{BaSO_4}$. Also, bromo group is reduced by $\ce{H_2}$ and Pd/$\ce{BaSO_4}$.

Comment: Hydrogenation is a standard method of removing benzyl ether protecting groups so there is ample precedent of cleaving O-Bn bonds whether ethers or alcohols. The stability of both the benzyl cation and radical facilitate this.

Comment: "Unusual" is a function of experience.

Comment: [This recent article](https://www.mdpi.com/1420-3049/25/14/3161) explains Zolpidem synthesis, which does not use $\ce{H2/Pd/BaSO4}$ after $\ce{PBr}$ reaction with allyl $\ce{OH}$ group as described in your methamphetamine synthesis route. There might be a mistake somewhere.